# formula for calculating p-value from t-distribution

Tags: excel, statistics

can anyone tell me about the symbol right after the word 'mode' in formula given at link below? I am looking to convert this formula into a computer program.

link : [https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_TDIST_function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_TDIST_function)

Comment: Try reloading your image in a free image file hosting site like http://imgur.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's the capital Greek letter [Gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma).  The probability density function of [Student's t distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-distribution) can be expressed in terms of the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#The_gamma_function_in_the_complex_plane), which is a sort of generalization of the factorial function.

[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is a nice little site where you can draw a mathematical symbol and find out what the LaTeX markup is for that symbol.  From the LaTeX markup, it's usually easy to find out what the symbol is called, or at the very least find something you can do a web search for.

C++, Ruby, Python, and Golang all include functions to compute (approximately) the Gamma function as part of their standard math libraries.  This is likely true of several other languages as well.

[image]